# Class Sheet methods getActiveCell, getCurrentCell, getActiveRange don't work as expected

Tags: google-apps-script

My spreadsheet has multiple sheets, one of which is 'File Names'. The desire is to get a particular file name, the one currently selected. Here's the function:

```
function getFileName (aSpreadsheet) {
  var aSheet=aSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('File Names');
  var sheetName = aSheet.getName();
  var aCell = aSheet.getActiveCell();
  var cellAddress = aCell.getA1Notation();
  var fileName = aCell.getValue();
  return fileName;
}
```

This code works as long as the 'File Names' sheet is currently active. But if some other sheet is currently active, it returns the value of the active cell in the active sheet rather than the selected cell of the 'File Names' sheet. It is getting the correct sheet; sheetName is 'File Names'. It doesn't matter if I use getActiveCell, getCurrentCell or getActiveRange, unless 'File Names' is the current active sheet it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show a copy of the sheet so we can see what you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: There's nothing special about the sheet except that its name is 'File Names' and a selected cell has a file name (or anything else) in it. This code will return the contents of the selected cell if that sheet is active. But if another sheet in the spreadsheet is active, it will return the contents of the active cell in that sheet.

Comment: I've put the function in a new sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-Lks8Drs3vYSoXUju4uKRDHM2Nzvg7RJ0ookXcZCi4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getFileName (aSpreadsheet) {
  var aSpreadsheet=aSpreadsheet||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//the default when aSpreadsheet is not defined by the parameter
  var aSheet=aSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('File Names');
  var sheetName=aSheet.getName();
  var aCell=aSheet.getActiveCell();
  var cellAddress=aCell.getA1Notation();
  var fileName=aCell.getValue();
  Logger.log(fileName);
  return fileName;
}
```

Comment: can you send a link to this sheet? Thanks

Comment: Thanks anyway. I don't see a significant difference between your code and mine. If yours works I'd like to know why.

Comment: I read the question more carefully and my script is behaving the same as yours.  Evidently `.getActiveCell` always refers to the activePage.

Comment: Thanks for checking.Do you agree a bug?

Comment: It doesn’t bug me